# SOLR Spellcheck not returning results

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

I'm having an annoying issue with the spellcheck component of solr 6.5.0. If I run a query through the spellcheck request handler, /spell, the query works as expected and I get suggested spelling for the incorrect words.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":42},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":{
      "injary":{
        "numFound":3,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":6,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"injury",
            "freq":121},
          {
            "word":"inward",
            "freq":3},
          {
            "word":"injure",
            "freq":1}]}},
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":{
      "collation":{
        "collationQuery":"injury",
        "hits":121,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "injary","injury"]},
      "collation":{
        "collationQuery":"inward",
        "hits":3,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "injary","inward"]},
      "collation":{
        "collationQuery":"injure",
        "hits":1,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "injary","injure"]}}}}
```

But if I run a query through the standard request handler, /select, I get no suggestions.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"injary",
      "indent":"on",
      "spellcheck":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1492780436450"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I modified the **solrconfig.xml** to bring the two request handlers into line as follows, the rest is default:

```
     <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">content</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
        <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
        <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
        <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
        <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
        <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
        <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
      </lst>

  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <!-- spell check component configuration -->
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

Comment: this is part of your `solrconfig.xml` and you have restarted Solr after having modified it?

Comment: I restarted after the changes

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was related to my managed-schema file.

I am parsing XML files and solr automatically adds the fields of the XML files to the managed-schema file as type strings. When I changed my dictionary field to type text_general it starting working as expected.

I hostly can't see how this worked but I made no other changes. I deleted my core and started from scratch to make sure I wasn't mistaken but it worked.